# Back button to go back in WebBrowser WP8 youtube site

Tags: windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I made a WebBrowser and it works except the back button in a youtube site. Youtube have a redirect to mobile version and this cause a loop

this code not works

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)" );
}
```

I know if it is a redirect (302) in this event?

webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

In the [WebBrowserControl documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)  you can find all available methods and events.
It is not very pretty but you should try that:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{        
    webBrowser.GoBack();
    e.Cancel = true;
}

void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("YouTubeUriYouGetAlwaysRedirectedTo"))
    {
        // Do some stuff here
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think an optimal solution. I should check if url is to YOUTUBE. if another site is the same problem? then it does not work

Comment: Ah okay, I got you wrong. Then you should use the Updating-Event of your webBrowser: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating(v=vs.105).aspx